# contact's name, created after SMS receiving, not showed in SMS notification, nor SMS app

Tags: android

I have app, that has internal list of contacts, that can differ from phones contact list. After SMS receiving, I am creating contact if the sender is in internal list (and not from "phones contacts") with

```
 ContentProviderOperation.Builder op=ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(... )
```

The contact is created, but the notification is not displaying senders name, only his number. I need to open SMS app, that refresh contacts. After this the notification is working well. 
In manifest I tried to set high priority, but it is not working:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.SMSReceiver"
        android:exported="true" android:priority="1000">>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

Is there any way how to notify the SMS manager/app, that it should refresh the contacts?

Other example: I have opened SMS app, SMS received and contact was created. I see new SMS thread, but only sender's number is shown. After app refresh (eg. by opening another app and back to SMS app, or opening SMS thread and back), the contact's name was shown correctly.